# elasticsearch transport-couchbase plugin refusing connection on port 9091

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, proxy, couchbase, xdcr

On my server I have installed elasticsearch-2.2.1 and couchbase server version 4.1.0. The aim is to transfer data from bucket x on couchbase to elastic search.

Ive installed the transport-couchbase plugin on elastic-search which will basically allow for xdcr from the server to elastic search.

As I understand it, transport-couchbase listens by default on port 9091 so in essence I'm supposed to create a cluster reference that points to that port (both couchbase and elastic search are installed on the same machine).

When I try create the reference I get an internal server error. The logs don't give me much information regarding the issue and I can ping the port. However when I try to telnet the machine on the port it refuses connection.

the server is sitting behind a proxy and i am starting to think that the issue lies within either couchbase server or elasticsearch ( transport-couchbase plugin)

Im going out on a limb here but I think maybe im supposed to configure the plugin so that it accepts requests going through tthe proxy. If this is the issue, is there a way to embed proxy settings into the plugin so that it can accept connections for xdcr?

PS: When I did this whole process on a separate machine that isnt sitting behind a proxy, everything worked fine. So I have a strong suspicion that it is proxy issues

Answer (score 2):

If you can't telnet or browse to port 9091, this most likely indicates a network config issue. The plugin binds to the interface that elasticsearch binds to. The first thing to check is that the bind_host and publish_host in elasticsearch.yml is configured to bind to an interface that allows connections from wherever the proxy is located and that the proxy is really connecting on that interface.

Comment: Thanks david, it seems there was another dev with a similar issue. He solved it by changing the network.host setting in the elasticsearch.yml file to be the IP address of the machine. I tried that and it worked beautifully

Comment: @Kazi, this is the correct answer. The `network.host` had to be set explicitly to `127.0.0.1` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread in github for the bug in transport plugin where it might not bind to all interfaces : 
 https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/issues/134

The above solutions didn't work for me, however I added this line:
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
to /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options and it seemed fixed the issue in my case